# TLS version on REST API URL

Tags: rest, ssl, docusignapi

I tried opening a ticket with Docusign Support, but they sent me this way instead. I'm hoping someone will be able to assist with this.

Starting on Nov. 16th at about 12:30 Central, we started getting errors in our application logs in our non-production environment. Upon investigation, it appears that https://demo.docusign.net/restapi started responding to TLSv1 queries with the following:

```
{
"errorCode": "TLS_INVALID_VERSION",
"message": "TLS Version is invalid, please update to TLS1.2 TLSv1.2 is 
required. Currently using TLSv1"
}
```

This came as a surprise to us considering that Docusign was supposed to disable TLSv1 in their non-production environment many months ago. Back then, we tested our application against the above URL (after the supposed switchover) and everything was working with our application, so we assumed that production would continue to work when that was supposed to switch over. And it did.

The issue is that it turns out that Docusign seems to have not disabled TLSv1 when they said they were supposed to, which invalidated any testing we did previously. And now, we're at risk of our production environment failing at some unknown point in the future.

So, does anyone know when Docusign will be switching over the production environment so that TLSv1 is disabled? We're investigating the option to update the libraries in the app so they support at least TLS 1.1, but that may take some time and this is a critical issue for us.

Hugh

p.s. On a side note, the site says that TLS v1.2 is required, but it still responds to TLS v1.1.

Comment: "does anyone know when Docusign will be switching over the production environment so that TLSv1 is disabled?" I do not see how anyone besides DocuSign itself can reply to that. As for your library upgrades problem, you could instead install a proxy such as Haproxy or nginx. This will be a TLS 1.2 client to DocuSign server while your local application will be a TLS 1.1 or 1.0 client to the proxy server, if you accept that the proxy terminates the connections.

Comment: Yeah, we are planning on setting up a proxy if we can't get the application fixed before the production environment is going to be switched over. However, we need to know when the switch is going to happen so we can plan that. 

And yeah, that's why I found it odd that Docusign Support would send us here, but they say that Docusign developers are supposed to frequent these parts and would be able to assist us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the publicly announced date for TLS 1.0 deprecation is 6/25/2018. However we had a grace period. Now the hard block dates are coming up. The hard block date in PROD is set at 1/31/2019. In Demo its 11/16, as you noticed.

Comment: Larry/Joey, thanks much for your replies. To clarify, the app only supports TLS v1 apparently, but the REST API site linked above says it only supports TLS v1.2 even though it will reply to a TLS v1.1 connection I make using curl.

Why is this deprecation date so far off from the messages that were sent out earlier this year? This in particular - https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/End-of-TLS-1-0-and-weak-cipher-support

Thanks,

Comment: The prev date announced was our intended date for deprecation. However in case customers did not move on, it was a soft date. Since then we've been working diligently with customers still on TLS 1.0 to get them off. The dates I posted above are hard dates (I'm going to edit the response to include this). Also yes, TLS 1.1 will still be supported, but guidance is to move to 1.2

Comment: Then why was this not communicated to customers? I saw the original notice about the deprecation, but nothing (as far as I recall) about it being a "soft date" and definitely nothing about the new 2018-11-16/2019-01-31 dates. And if Docusign was contacting my company about us still using TLS v1, it didn't get passed on to me.

Comment: Hi Hugh, we've ask internally to get a cleaner message out. Apologize for the confusion, it's good feedback for us in how to handle these types of communication in future.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before calling REST API

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
It will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I work for DocuSign.

As of this writing, DocuSign has no current plans to stop supporting TLS 1.1. We already support TLS 1.2 and encourage you to upgrade to it rather than TLS 1.1. But TLS 1.1 is fine if that is all your stack currently supports.