# TLS_INVALID_VERSION TLS Version is invalid, please update to TLS1.2 TLSv1.2 is required. Currently using TLSv1

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign PHP package for my octobercms web app. I am trying to connect to docusign sanbox through api and I'm stuck with this error message.

```
TLS_INVALID_VERSION TLS Version is invalid, please update to TLS1.2 TLSv1.2 is required. Currently using TLSv1
```

Did some research on web and figured TLS1.1 is deprecated? Now how do update to TLSV1.2 ? I am using Mamp on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [TLS version on REST API URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487042/tls-version-on-rest-api-url) .  Docusign deprecated TLS v1.0 in the demo environment in mid-November, and will be doing so in Prod on 1/31/2019.  According to that post, 1.1 or 1.2 are supported, the message is a bit misleading.

Comment: But do you know how to not show the above error and make the code actually work?

Answer (score 0):

The message is not quite correct. TLS 1.1 is supported, along with TLS 1.2. TLS 1.2 is recommended.

By googling, I found a [document](https://github.com/lunr/mamp-curl-tls) about upgrading the TLS version for Mamp...